# What is the difference between these python functions?

Tags: python, functions

What is the difference between this:

```py
def total(initial=10, *numbers, **keywords):  
     count = initial  
    for fake in numbers:  
        count = count + fake  
    for key in keywords:  
        count = count + keywords[key]  
    return count  
print total(10, 5, fruits=10)
```

and this:

```py
def total(initial=10, *numbers, **keywords):  
    count = initial        
    for fake in numbers:                      
        count = count + fake    
    for key in keywords:   
        count = count + key   
    return count   
print total(10, 5, fruits=10)
```

The thing i don't get here is in the 1st program it accepts keywords and in the second program i keep getting errors about keywords!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just a single change between two code snippets, the first one uses:

```
count = count + keywords[key]
```

while the second one uses:

```
count = count + key
```

In case of the first one you are taking the value of a key of the dictionary and then adding the value to the previous count.

While in the second case you are adding the key (string) itself to the integer count, which is giving an error expectedly.

This will make you more clear:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
def total(initial=10, *numbers, **keywords):
    count = initial
    for fake in numbers:
        count = count + fake
    for key in keywords:
        print 'key is: ' + key
        print 'keyword is: ' + str(keywords)
        count = count + keywords[key]
    return count
```

I have added two lines to check the values to which my input is being interpreted as.

Now when i run:

```
print total(10, 5, fruits=10)
```

it gives:

```
key is: fruits
keyword is: {'fruits': 10}
25
```

I would suggest you to go though the basic [data types](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) used in `python`.

Comment: so using the object keywords in l8 will take the value of, that is assigned to the variable right?

Comment: @froyo Its not a variable & value anymore, its a dictionary..unless you know how dictionaries work in python you would not get it..i am sorry..my suggestion would be to go through the basic data types, once you get a hold of them you will get it  :)